# How to convert from alphabets to pixels

Tags: string, matrix, character, pixelate

Do you know a program or script that converts from a letter to a matrix (consisting of 0 and 1) representing the letter? 
For example, from letter I to a matrix something like this: (it's an LED pannel showing letter I):

[image: example]

Please let me know a way to create such matrix other than hand typing
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution is to use font.

1. **well for HW implementation I usually used EGA/VGA 8x8 font**

   extracted from gfx card **BIOS** you can do it easy in **MS-DOS** environment
2. **another way is to extract font programaticaly from image**

   draw entire font to bitmap (in line or in matrix ..., or use some already created like mine). Use fixed pitch, font size most suitable your needs and do not forget that almost none modern font supports fixed pitch so use `OEM_CHARSET` and `System` named font from it. Set color properly (ideal is black background and white font) and read image pixel by pixel and store it as table of numbers. Pixel with not background color is set pixel.

   **Do not compare to font color because of anti-aliasing and filters**. Now read all characters and set/res corresponding bit inside font table. First compute start `x,y` of character in image (from **ASCII** code and image organization) then do 2 nested 8-steps `x,y` for loops (in order according to your `font[]` organization)

   `set/res` corresponding `font[]` bits at addresses `8*ASCII` to  `8*ASCII+8`
3. **I assume you use MCU to control LED panel**

   the font organization in memory is usually that 8-bit number represents single row in character. Of course if your **LED** panel is meant to display animated scroll then column organization of font and also HW implementation will ease things up a lot. If you have 16 bit **MCU** and **IO** access than you can use `16-bit` / pixels font size.

   if you have more than 8 pixels and only 8 bit MCU you can still use 16 bit data but the IO access will be in two steps via two IO ports instead of 1. **I strongly recommend whole data-wide IO access instead of set/res individual IO lines** its much quicker and can prevent flickering

OK here is my old `8x8` font I used back in the days ... I think this one is extracted from **EGA/VGA BIOS** but I am not shore ... it was too many years ago

[image: fixed pitch 8x8 font]

Now the fun part

```
const BYTE font[8*256]={ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ... }
```

any character is represented as 8 numbers. if bit is `0` then it means paper (background pixel) if bit is `1` then it means ink (font pixel). Now there are more combinations (left to right, up to down and their combinations)

OK ( row-vise | left to right | up to down ) organization means:

- first number is up most row of char
- **msb** is left most pixel
- **lsb** is right most pixel

so for example char '1' in `8x8` will be something like this (b means binary number):

```
00000000b,
00001000b,
00011000b,
00101000b,
00001000b,
00001000b,
00111100b,
00000000b,
```

When you have extracted all characters to font table than save it as source code to file which you will later include in your **MCU** code (can be placed in **EEPROM** for pgm-code)

Now the algorithm to print char on **LED** panel is strongly depended on your HW implementation

- so please post a circuit diagram of interconnection between LED panel and control system
- specify target platform and language
- specify desired functionality

I assume you want left moving scroll by pixel step

1. **the best fit will be if your LED panel is driven by columns not rows**

   You can activate single column of **LED**s by some **data IO** port (all bits can be active at a time) and selecting which one column is active is driven by another **select IO** port (only single bit can be active at a time). So in this case compute the start address of the column to display in font table:

   - `address = (8*ASCII + x_offset)`
   - send `font[8*ASCII + x_offset]` to **data IO** port
   - activate **select IO** port with the correct bit active
   - wait a while (1-10ms) ... so you can actually see the light  if delay is too short then there is no brightness if delay is too long then there is flickering so you need to experiment a little (depends on number of select bits).
   - deactivate **select IO** port
   - repeat with the next column
   - `x_offset` is the scrolling shift
2. **if your HW implementation does not fit in such way don't worry**

   just use bit SHIFT,AND,OR operations to create the data words in memory and then send them in similar manner

Hope it helps a litle

Comment: Oh and if you are low on memory you can use just the alphabet and numbers ... forget about the special characters so you will have less font data, but then your string encoding must match your font ... or skip first 32 chars and last 128 chars which spares more than half of memory

Comment: @user1776194 I can see you have no answers checked yet ... if any answer to your question is helpful you can vote (I am not sure if you can vote immediately or need some rep for it)  it up by that little triangle above vote number, if it is wrong, abusive ... then you can vote it down by that triangle belove the same number. if the answer leads to resolving your problem you should check it by clicking on the check sign below vote triangles. It will award rep points to the answer author and also mark your question as answered. (also I think you will earn some badges like accepted first answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find a font that looks the way you want (probably a monospaced font such as Courier), draw/rasterize it with a certain size (8pt?), without anti-aliasing, and convert the resulting image to your matrix format.